# Explain why the function $f$: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ is not surjective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I encountered this question in a problem set recently. The easiest way to explain why the statement is true is to prove that its range is not equal to its codomain. The range of $f$ is $[0, \infty)$.

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what a codomain is so can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define $f : A \to B$, then $B$ is the codomain. The range of $f$ is always a subset of the codomain, i.e. $\mathrm{range}(f) \subseteq B$ (but there need not be equality).

If $f$ is surjective, then $\mathrm{range}(f) = B$ (rather than merely being a subset).

Since $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^2$ has $\mathrm{range}(f) = [0,\infty)$ but $\mathrm{codomain}(f) = \Bbb R$ and $[0,\infty) \ne \mathbb{R}$, we would thus say that $f$ is not surjective.

For instance, while $(-1) \in \mathrm{codomain}(f) = \Bbb R$, there is no $x \in \mathrm{domain}(f) = \Bbb R$ for which $f(x) = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

The codomain is where the output of the function lives, in this case, you're given a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, so the codomain/target space is $\Bbb{R}$. And clearly, $[0,\infty)$ is not the same as $\Bbb{R}$.

The codomain/target space is like "where the outputs all live" (think of a big dart board). The range/image is that portion of the codomain which is actually hit by your function (the points you actually hit on the dart board).